# ListView, is there a simple way to allow dragging of items internally (built-in)?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listview, draggable

I was wondering if there was a simple way of doing this (setting a property or something of the ListView) rather than going through the Drag events.

All I want is similar functionality to Windows Explorer, where users can drag the ListViewItems within the ListView and when dropped they remain where the user left them. All I want to know is if there is functionality like this built in to the list view? If not then I will have to do it with the drag events, but I don't want to be doing any unnecessary work if I don't have to!

Thanks,

**Update**
The answers I've had have all appeared to be using example projects which contain drag drop functionality, I appreciate the answers, although I already understand how to do this. The question is aimed at whether or not there is any in-built functionality of the ListView that I can take advantage of for internal dragging of ListViewItems.